# bidi, RTL and \write

Tags: right-to-left, bidi, write

In order to solve one issue with reledmac in RTL, I made some test with \write and bidi.

In the following MWE, only the first `\write` works. It I delete the `\RTL`, all the `\write` work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\RTL
\newwrite\toto
\openout\toto=\jobname.sty
\write\toto{1}ssss
\write\toto{2}ssss
\write\toto{3}ssss
\closeout\toto

s
\end{document}
```

What about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were lucky that 1 got output, if you use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\RTL
\leavevmode\newwrite\toto
\openout\toto=\jobname.sty
\write\toto{1}ssss
\write\toto{2}ssss
\write\toto{3}ssss
\closeout\toto

s
\end{document}
```

then nothing will be written to the file,

The problem is the tex--xet bidirectional model that xetex inherited from etex. right to left directionality isn't built in to the system at a low level the way it is in the model luatex inherited from omega, it is essentially a simple pass that reverses nodes (just) in horizontal boxes.

So in vertical mode (the file open and the first `\write` in your example, it's OK but the line of the paragraph with the later writes and the file close, the nodes are reversed, and so the file close happens first, which means the `\write` are writing to a closed file so just appear on the terminal and log.

One possible scheme would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\def\foo#1{\ifvmode#1\else\vadjust{#1}\fi}
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\RTL
\foo{\newwrite\toto}
\openout\toto=\jobname.sty
\foo{\write\toto{1}}ssss
\foo{\write\toto{2}}ssss
\foo{\write\toto{3}}ssss
\foo{\closeout\toto}

s
\end{document}
```

Comment: so we need to be in a vertical mode to use `\write` in RTL ?

Comment: @Maïeul not necessarily, especially for `\write` if you know that the entries are written in the wrong order you can usually fix it up when the file is used, but if you do \openout and \closeout in the wrong order, that's bad.

Comment: @Maïeul updated answer

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will look on it with a fresh brain, so not tonight ;-)

Comment: Unfortunatly, this solution made problem when implementing in reledmac : it add spurious lines. I have found an other solution, anyway (https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/commit/000e7c8b9bce38a0249e32ab583a037cffa0c287)