# Problem with reledmac and lemma substitution, error '\iflemmacommand@0' undefined

Tags: reledmac, arabxetex, lemma

I'm writing a critical edition of an Arabic text with reledmac ed arabxetex.
I'm using the command \lemma{} to change the lemma passed to the critical note.
Basically, the compilation produces the expected result in the pdf, but it also gives some '\iflemmacommand@0' error (from package etoolbox).
My question are:

- what is this error? can I safely ignore it?
- moreover, why the error comes out only for some \lemma and not for all?

I attach a MWE with seven \lemma{...}, all with the same syntax, but only two of them give rise to the '\iflemmacommand@0' error (probably the first and one of the last).
I have tried to change the quantity of text in \edtext{}, to change the order of the lemma or the content, but I get no hints to why only those two \lemma give trouble while the others work correctly.

Thank you very much for any suggestion!
BR

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm, heightrounded}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}
\usepackage[series={A}, noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, noledgroup ]{reledmac}
\Xafterrule{8pt}
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}
\Xlemmaseparator{]}
\lineation{page}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Afootnoterule}{\right@footnoterule\par}
\makeatother

\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A]
\Xgroupbyline[A]
\Xlinerangeseparator{\null-\null}
\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}
\Xsymlinenum{|}
\Xnotenumfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage{arabxetex}

\newcommand{\ta}[1]{\textarab[voc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\tanv}[1]{\textarab[novoc]{#1}}

\newcommand{\myLR}[1]{\textLR{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\author{The Autor}
\title{Edizione araba}
\maketitle

\chapter{Il \textarab{kitAb al-malakI} di al-Ma\v{g}us\={i}: verso un'edizione critica}

\begin{arab}
\beginnumbering
\pstart

    \edtext{al-^guz'_u al-'wwalu min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`Ti  al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-Al-malakI ta.snIfu al-^say_.hi al-a"mAmi al-`Amili al-`Alimi al-.fA.dili  al-mu.haqqiqi al-mufIdi a"'bU al-.hasan `lI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-ma^gUsI tilmI_di al-.hakImi al-fA-.dili a"'bI mAhir mUsY bn sayyAr `fA al-ll_ahu ta`alY `anhu bimihnaTi wakarimihi bismi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmani al-ra.hImi rabbu a"'`azza wa tammama yA karImu kitAbu kAmilu al-.sinA`Ti al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-Al-malakI ta.snIfu `alI bn al-`abbAs al-ma^gUsI tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY bn sayyAr lilmalaki `a.dud al-dawlaTi ra.himahum  al-ll_ahu a"'^gm`ayni al-maqAlatu al-'UlY wa hya _hamsatu wa `i^srUna bAbAN}{
    \lemma{al-^guz'_u \dots\ bAbAN}
    \Afootnote{\tanv{al-^guz|"'u al-a"'wwalu min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi fI al-.tibbi al-ma`rUfu bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alY i"'bn al-`abbAs waqad ^ga`alahu ^guzy"'ayni warattaba kulla ^guz|"'iN minhA `alY `a^sraTi maqAlAtiN wa^ga`ala kulla maqAlaTiN ta^stamilu `alY `iddaTi a"'bwAbiN wa^gumlaTu a"'bwAbihi bitamAmihi sab`umAy"'iaTi wa sittatUna bAbAN wah_a_dA al-^guz|"'u hwa yu.dIfu al-kitAba waya^stamilu `alY `a^sraTi maqAlAtiN tamAmAN - bismi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm rabbu a"'n`amat farduN - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min al-.hurfi al-a"'wwali min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfaTi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr wahya _hamsatU wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{D}, \tanv{bismi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm rabbu a"'n`amat walahu al-.hamdu wa.hdihi - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min al-^guz|"'i al-a"'wwali min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfu `alI ... al-muta.tabbibu tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"bn sayyAri wahya _hamsaTu wa`'^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{E}, \tanv{bismi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm wa.salwatuhu `alY saydI mu.hammad wa `alY i"'lhi wa.sa.hbihi wa ... - i"'btada"' al.maqAlaTu al-a"'UlY min al-^guz|"'i al-a"'wwali min al-`ilmi min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfu bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn ^sayyAn wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{F}, \tanv{bismi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm  wamA tawfIqI ... bi-al-ll_ahi al-`alY al-.hamdu lill_ahu a"'.haqqi min .hamdiN waa"'wlY min ma^gdi i"'lhAN wA.hidAN  i"'.hdAN fardAN .samadAN mutafarridAN .hannAnAN mannAnAN man `alY _hilqaTi bi"'n^sA"'i bihim lA min ^saIy"'iN kAy"'niN qablahu bal a"'bda`a nUrAN fa^ga`alahu nasbAN _tum a"'n^sa"' minhu ma kAna qad ... fa"'^grY `alY ^gamI`ihA al-.tA`aTa i"'lY a"'_h_dihA lA ya"'tIhu al-bA.tilu min bayna badnihi wala min _ha.tfihi ... min .hakImiN .hamIdiN wa"'^shada a"'nna lA i"'laha i"'llA al-ll_ahi wa.hdihi lA ^sarIkuN lahu waa"'^shada a"'nna mu.hammad `abduhu warasUluhu .salY al-ll_ahu `alayhi wa`alY i"'lahi wasallama wa^sarrafa ... - kitAbu kAmilu al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfu bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi ... ra.himahu al-ll_ahu `alayhi - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'UlY wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{G}, \tanv{bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm wa.sallY al-ll_ahu `alY mu.hammad nabIhi al-karImi wa`alY i"'lahi wasallam taslImAN walA .hawla walA qwwaTa i"'llA bi-ll_ahi al-`alY ... - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min al-^guz|"'i al-a"'wwali min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbayaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-ma^gUsI al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_di a"'bI al-.hasani mUsA i"'bn sayyAr wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{H}, \tanv{kitAbu kAmilu al-.sinA`aTi al-malakI ta.snIfu `alI i"'bn `abbAs al-ma^gUsI al-a"'^gAnI al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_du a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi .gafara al-ll_ahu lahum a"'^gmayni - bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm rabbu ... - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min al-^guz|"'i al-a"'wwali min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta.snIfi `alY i"'bn al-`abbAs al-ma^gUsI al-a"rra^gAnI al-muta.tabbibi tilmi_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"?bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi wayata.dammanu _hamsaTa wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{I}, \tanv{al-^guz|"'u al-a"'wwalu min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi wahwa fI al-`ilmi way^stamilu `alY _hamsaTi maqAlAtiN al-a"'uUlY waal-_tAnyaTu waal-_tAli_taTu waal-rAbi`aTu waal-_hAmisaTu ta"'lIfu `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs tilmI_du a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr al-ma^gUsI al-muta.tabbibi ra.himahu al-ll_ahu ta`AlY - bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm wabihi nasta`Inu rabbi saydi - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alY i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmi_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr al-ma^gUsI wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{J}, \tanv{kitAbu kAmilu al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alY i"'bn al-`abbAs al-ma^gUsI al-muta.tabbibi tilmI:di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr wahwa yanqasimu qismayni na.zarI wa`amalI wa ^gamI`uhumA ya.htawI `alY `i^srIna maqAlatiN al-na.zarI minhu `a^sraTu maqAlAtiN waal-`amalI ka_d_alika wa^gamI`uhumA ya.htawI `alY sab`amAy"'aTi bAbiN wasittaTi wasab`Ina bAbAN ya.htawI al-na.zarI minha `alY mAy"'atayni bAbiN wa _hamisaTi wa sittatIna bAbAN waya.htawI al-^guz|"'u al-`amalI minhA `alY _hamisamAy"'aTiN bAbiN wa"'i.hda `a^sara bAbAN waal-ll_ahu al-mwaffiqu lil.sawAbi - wa.sala al-ll_ahu saydanA mu.hammad wa`alY i"'lahi wa.sa.habihi wasallama wa^sarrafa wakarrama - maqAlAtuN h_a_dA al-sa.gIru ... wawa.sAyA al-muta.tabbibIna wa`ahdi buqrA.t ... - min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{K}, \tanv{al-^guz|"'u al-a"'wwalu min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi ta"'lIfu `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi - bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm al-ll_ahum a"'`azza - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{L}, \tanv{bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm rabbu a"'n`amata farduN - al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr wahya _hamsaTu wa`'^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{N}, \tanv{bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-.ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm kitAbu kAmilu al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi  al-ma`rUfi bi-al-malakI ta.sinIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi al-ma^gUsI al-a"'rrmAnI tilmI_di a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr lilmaliki `a.dud al-dawlaTi i"'bn rukn al-dawlaTi ra.dY al-ll_ahu `anhumA al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY wahya _hamsaTu wa`'^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{O}, \tanv{bi"'smi al-ll_ahi al-.ra.hmAn al-ra.hIm wa.sala al-ll_ahu saydanA mu.hammad wai"'lahi wa.sa.habihi wasallama taslImAN ka_tIrAN al-maqalaTu al-a"'UlY min kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi al-.tibbyaTi al-ma`rUfu bi-al-malakI ta"'lIfi `alI i"'bn al-`abbAs al-muta.tabbibi tilmIdu a"'bI mAhir mUsY i"'bn sayyAr wahya _hamsaTu wa`i^srUna bAbAN} \myLR{B} }}

    \begin{enumerate}\itemindent=4em
    \item al-bAbu \edtext{al-'wwalu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{min al-maqAlaTi al-a"'uUlY} \myLR{post add. A}}} fI .sadri al-kitAbi
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAnI fI \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{\tanv{\edtext{`ahdi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-'amAmi} \myLR{post add. A}}} \edtext{i"'buqrA.t}{\Afootnote{\tanv{i"'bu.grA.t} \myLR{EH, sic in omni sententia;}   \tanv{buqrA.t} \myLR{GIL}}} \edtext{\tanv{wawa.sAyA al-muta.tabbibIna}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wa.gayrihi min al-muta.tabbibIna}\myLR{I}}}}}{
    \lemma{\tanv{`ahdi \dots al-muta.tabbibIna}}
    \Afootnote{\tanv{fI _dikri wa.sAyA i"'buqrA.t wa .gyrihi min qudamA'_i al-muta.tabbibIna} \myLR{BDEHJKN;} \tanv{wa.gayrihim waal-a"'_hlA.tu al-ll_atI yanba.gI a"'n yata_hllaqa bihA al-.tabIbu} \myLR{post. add. D}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{`ahdi i"'buqrA.t lilmuta.tabbibIna} \myLR{F}}} 
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAli_tu \edtext{fI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{_dikri} \myLR{post add. BDEHIJKN}}} al-ruw"'Usi \edtext{al-_tamAnyaTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. J}}} \edtext{\tanv{al-ll_atI yanba.gI a"'n tu`alamu qabla \edtext{qira"'Ti}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. et add. marg. J, fortasse add. marg. N sed non potest bene legi ruinae causa}}} kulliN kitAbiN}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. EGLO}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-rAbi`u fI qismaTi al-.tibbi
    \item al-bAbu al-_hAmisu fI \edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{_dikri} \myLR{DEGJKN; om. F}}} al-a"'us.tuqsAt \edtext{wamAhyatihA}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. FGLO}}} \item al-bAbu al-sAdisu \edtext{fI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{.siffaTi} \myLR{post add. BDEHJKN}; \tanv{ma`rufaTi} \myLR{post add. I}}} 'a.snAfi al-mizA^gi
    \item al-bAbu al-sAbi`u fI al-ma`AnI al-ll_atI \edtext{\tanv{yunqasamu} \edtext{'ilayhA}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. N, fortasse add. marg. sed non poteste legi}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'ilayhA yanqasimu} \myLR{EHK}}} \edtext{\tanv{kulluN wA.hiduN min 'a.snAfi al-mizA^gi}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. F}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAminu fI \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{al-i"'stidlAli}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-i"'stidlAlAtu}\myLR{I}}} `alY}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta`rrufi} \myLR{BDHJKN}; \tanv{ta`rIfi} \myLR{E}}} mizA^gi kulliN wA.hidiN \edtext{\tanv{min \edtext{\tanv{al-nAsi 'ayy mizA^giN hWa}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-nAsi bi-al-.tab`i} \myLR{BDEHJKN}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'.snAfi al-mizA^gi} \myLR{F}}} 
    \item al-bAbu al-tAsi`u fI \edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta`arrufi} \myLR{BDHJKN}; \tanv{ta`rIfi} \myLR{E}}} \edtext{\tanv{mizA^gi \edtext{\tanv{kulliN wA.hidiN min al-a"'`.dA'_i al-_ha.s.su bihi}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. G et add. marg. G^{1}}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-a"'`.dA'_i} \myLR{FL}; \tanv{mizA^gi al-a"'`.dA'_i wamA yu_hi.s.su kullaN wA.hidaN minhA} \myLR{O}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-`A^siru fI \edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI al-i"'stidlali `alY}\myLR{BDEHJKN}}} \edtext{mizA^gi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. F}; \tanv{hyyaTi} \myLR{post add. J}}} al-dimA.gi
    \item al-bAbu al-.hAdyY `a^sara fI \edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta`arrufi} \myLR{BDHJKN ita in omni sequente sententia}; \tanv{ta`rIfi} \myLR{E}}} \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{mizA^gi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. D}; \tanv{al-a"'`.dA'_i wa 'awlAN fI} \myLR{ante add. A}}} \edtext{al-`ayni}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-`aynaini} \myLR{BDEHJK}}} wa sAy"'iri al-.hawAssi}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{mizA^gi al-`aynaini} \myLR{F}}} 
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAnY `a^sara fI \edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. et . add. supra lineam O}, \tanv{ta`rIfi} \myLR{EI}}} mizA^gi al-qalbi
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAli-tu `a^sara fI\edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta`arrufi} \myLR{E, ita in sequentibus quattuor}}} mizA^gi al-kibdi
    \item al-bAbu al-rAbi`u `a^sara fI ma`rufaTi\edtext{mizA^gi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. H}}} al-a"'un_tayayini 
    \item al-bAbu al-_hAmisu `a^sara fI ma`rufaTi mizA^gi al-ma`idaTi
    \item al-bAbu al-sAdisu `a^sara fI ma`rufaTi mizA^gi al-ri'yaTi 
    \item al-bAbu al-sAbi`u `a^sara fI ma`rufaTi mizA^gi \edtext{^gumlaTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. F}}} al-badni
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAminu `a^sara \edtext{\tanv{fI ma`rufaTi mizA^gi al-badni \edtext{al-mu`tadili}{\Afootnote{\tanv{bi-al-^gumlaTi} \myLR{F}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI `alAmAti al-badni al-mu`tadili al-mizA^gi} \myLR{BDEHJKN}}} 
    \item al-bAbu al-tAsi`u `a^sara fI \edtext{\tanv{ma`rufaTi al-'asbAbi al-mu.gayyiraTi lildalAy'li \edtext{\tanv{`alY al-a"'mzi^gaTi al-.tabI`yaTi}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. A}, \tanv{`an al-mizA^gi al-.tabI`I} \myLR{post add. F}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI al-a"'sbAbi al-ll_atI tu.gayyiru al-dalAy"'la `alY al-a"'mzi^gaTi} \myLR{B}, \tanv{fI al-i"'stidlAli bimA `alY al-a"'mzi^gaTi al-.tabI`IaTi} \myLR{D}; \tanv{fI al-a"'sbAbi al-ll_atI tu.gayyiru al-dalAy"'la `alY al-a"'mzi^gaTi al-.tabI`IaTi} \myLR{EHK}; \tanv{mizA^gi al-a"'^syA|"'i al-ll_atI yu.gayyiru al-dalAy"'ila} \myLR{G}; \tanv{al-a"'^syA|"'i al-muta.gayyaraTi `an al-a"'mri al-.tabI`I}\myLR{I}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-`i^srUna \edtext{fI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ma`rufaTi} \myLR{post add. A}; \tanv{ta`arrufi} \myLR{post add. N}}} ta.gayyiri \edtext{mizA^gi \edtext{al-badni}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. GO}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{mizA^gi al-a"'bdAni al-.tabi`yaTi} \myLR{B}, \tanv{mizA^gi al-a"'bdAni} \myLR{DEHJKN}}} min \edtext{qabla}{\Afootnote{\tanv{^gihaTi} \myLR{G}}} \edtext{al-buldAni}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-baladi} \myLR{BEHJK}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-.hAdyY wa `i^srUna fI \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{ma`rufaTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. FILNO}}} \edtext{ta.gayyiri}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'n} \myLR{post add. F}}} al-mizA^gi min \edtext{qabla}{\Afootnote{\tanv{^gihaTi} \myLR{G}}} al-i"'nsAni}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI _dikri .tabAy"'i al-i"'nsAni wata.gayyari dalAy"'ili al-mizA^gi bisababihA} \myLR{BDEHK}, \tanv{fI _dikri .tabAy"'`i al-i"'nsAni wata.gayyari al-a"'mzi^gaTi bisababihA}\myLR{J}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAnI wa `i^srUna \edtext{fI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ma`rufaTi} \myLR{post add. G}}} \edtext{\tanv{ta.gayyri al-mizA^gi min qabla}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI .tabI`aTi} \myLR{BDEHJK}; \tanv{kayfyaTi .tabI`aTi} \myLR{N}}} \edtext{\tanv{al-_dikri wa al-a"'un_tY}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-a"'un_tY waal-_dikri} \myLR{O}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-_tAli_tu wa `i^srUna fI ta.gayyiri al-mizA^gi min \edtext{qabla}{\Afootnote{\tanv{^gihaTi} \myLR{G}}} \edtext{al-`AdaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-`AdAti} \myLR{N}}}
    \item al-bAbu al-rAbi`u wa al-`i^srUna \edtext{fI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta.gayyri} \myLR{post add. et delevit O}}} dalAy"'ili al-.sa.h.haTi \edtext{wa}{\Afootnote{\tanv{`alY} \myLR{A}}} \edtext{^sarI}{\Afootnote{\tanv{bi^sarri}\myLR{H}}} al-`abIdi
    \item al-bAbu al-_hAmisu wa al-`i^srUna fI .siffaTi \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{\tanv{al-`ilmi bia"'mri}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. FLO}}}  al-a"'_hlA.ti \edtext{al-a"'rba`aTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. AGHKL, non potest legi E}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-`ilmi bi-al-a"'_hlA.ti al-a"'rba`aTi}\myLR{I}}}
    \end{enumerate}

    \edtext{\tanv{al-maqAlaTu al-a"'uUlY \edtext{min}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-^guz|"'i al-a"'wwali} \myLR{post add. F}}} kitAbi kAmili al-.sinA`aTi \edtext{al-.tibbyaTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. O}}}}}{
    \lemma{\tanv{al-maqalaTu \dots al-.tibbyaTi}}
    \Afootnote{\myLR{om. BDEGHIJKN}; \tanv{i"'btada"'} \myLR{ante add. FGLO}}} 
    
    \edtext{\tanv{al-bAbu al-'awwalu fI .sadri al-kitAbi}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. BL}}} 
    
    \edtext{\tanv{qAla `alI ibn \edtext{al-`abbAs}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al}\myLR{om. H}, \tanv{al-muta.tabbibu} \myLR{post add. AN}}}}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. LO, postea add.} O1}} i"'nna 'a.haqqa mA 'ibtad'a bihi fI ^gamI`i \edtext{al-'amUri}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. BDEHK}}} \edtext{waal-'a.hawAli}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. G}}} \edtext{.hamdu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{_dikru} \myLR{DJ}}} \edtext{al-ll_ahi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ta`AlY} \myLR{post add. FG}}} wa al-_tanA'_u `alayhi waal-^sukru lahu falahu al-.hamdu _hAliqi al-_halqi biqudratihi wabAsi.ti al-rizqi \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{bira.himatihi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{bi.hikmatihi} \myLR{BDEHKN}}} \edtext{waal-mAnnu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-bayyAnu} \myLR{F}}} `alY `ibAdihi bifa.dlihi waal-mu`.tI \edtext{lahum}{\Afootnote{\tanv{yaqdirunahu} \myLR{post add. O}}} mA \edtext{\tanv{yaqdirUna bihi}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{yaqdirUnahu} \myLR{E}}} `alY \edtext{'i.slA.hi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{.salA.hi}\myLR{J}; \tanv{i"'.s.tilA.hi}\myLR{L}}} \edtext{ma`AI^sihim}{\Afootnote{\myLR{post corr. I; corr. marg. J}}} fI al-dunyA waal-fawzi fI al-A"'_hiraTi wahUa al-`aqlu al-ll_a_dI huwa \edtext{sababuN}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-sababu \myLR{B}}}} likulliN _haIriN wamiftA.hu likulliN naf`iN wasabIl 'ilY al-na^gATi}}{
    %\lemma{\tanv{bira.himatihi \dots al-na^gATi}}
    \Afootnote{\myLR{non potest legi in K damni causa}}} wabihi fa.ddala al-ll_ahu \edtext{\tanv{^galla wa`azza}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{sab.hAnahu} \myLR{post add. B}, \tanv{`azza wa^galla} \myLR{BEFHK}; \tanv{ta`AlY} \myLR{post add. G}; \myLR{om. L}; \tanv{ta`AlY} \myLR{O}}} al-'insAna `alY \edtext{sA'iri}{\Afootnote{\tanv{om.} O \tanv{et add. marg.} O1}} mA _halaqa min \edtext{\tanv{.hayawAniN \edtext{wabanAtiN}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'w banAtiN}\myLR{H}}}}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-hayawAni waal-banAti} \myLR{F}}} wa.gayrihumA 
    
    \edtext{\tanv{\edtext{'ammA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wa} \myLR{ante add. G}}} ba`da \edtext{faqad}{\Afootnote{\tanv{waqad} \myLR{E}}} 'as`ada al-ll_ahu al-malika al-^galIla al-karIma al-`un.sura \edtext{al-fA.dila}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-mif.dala} \myLR{post add. N}}} al-^gawahiza `a.duda \edtext{al-dawlaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-ll_ahu} \myLR{G}; \tanv{a"'.tAla al-ll_ahu baqAy"'ahu wakabata a"'`dAhu} \myLR{post. add. DGIJ}; \tanv{a"'.tAla al-ll_ahu baqAy"'ahu wa"'dAma salAmatahu wadawlatahu wa"'`azza na.srahu wakabata a"'`dAhu} \myLR{post add. F}; \tanv{a"'.tAla al-ll_ahu baqAy"'ahu wakabata a"'`dAhu wa"'dAma salAmatahu wadawlatahu wa"'`azza nu.sratahu} \myLR{post add. N}}} \edtext{bimA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fImA} \myLR{G}}} \edtext{_ha.s.sahu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-ll_ahu}\myLR{post add. HIO}}} \edtext{bihi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. et add. supra lineam et marg. K}}} min al-fa.dA'ila al-nafsiyyaTa \edtext{\tanv{waal-manAqiba al-^sarIfaTa \edtext{fa'a`.tAhu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wa"'`.tAhu} \myLR{FGHIKNO, postea corr. K}}} min al-`aqli a"'aUfarahu wamin al-fahimi 'a.gzarahu wamin al-_dihni 'al.tafahu wamin al-_halqi 'abhAhu wamin \edtext{al-_halqi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-_halUqi} \myLR{E}}} 'ar.dAhu wamin al-dIni \edtext{'a.hsanahu}{\Afootnote{\myLR{post corr. F}}} wamin \edtext{al-.hilmi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-.hukmi} \myLR{I}}} 'aq.sadahu wamin \edtext{al.hayA'_i}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-.haywaTu} \myLR{G, sic; corr. marg. G^{?}}}} 'a.hmadahu wamin al-rAI \edtext{'a.swabahu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'a^gwAdahu} \myLR{G}}} wamin al-tadbIri \edtext{'a^gwadahu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'a.swabahu} \myLR{G}; \tanv{fI a"'u_hrY wamin al-.hayA|"'i a"'.hamdahu} \myLR{add. marg. K cum signo super hoc verbum}}} wamin al-fa.dli 'akmalahu wamin al-_tanA|"'i 'a^gmalahu wamin al-'anfusi \edtext{'akbarahA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'kramahA} \myLR{E}}} wamin al-himami 'ab`adahA wamin al-^sa^gA`aTi \edtext{'abr`ahA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'bda`ahA} \myLR{G}; \tanv{a"'tra`ahA} \myLR{H}; \myLR{om.} N \myLR{et add. marg.} N1}} wamin \edtext{al-.ha.sAfaTi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-fa.sA.haTi} \myLR{BIJNO}; \tanv{al-_hi.tAbaTi} \myLR{K et iteravit marg. post damnum}}} 'abla.gahA \edtext{\tanv{wamin al-balA.gaTi 'atimmahA}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. I}}} wamin al-samA.haTi 'a`ammahA wamin \edtext{al-min.taqi}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-nu.tqi} \myLR{BIJ}}} \edtext{'a.hlAhu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'^gladahu} \myLR{K}}} wamin al-malaki \edtext{'asnAhu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'asmAhu} \myLR{G}}} \edtext{\tanv{wamin al-`azzi \edtext{'asmAhu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'asnAhu} \myLR{G}}}}}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om.} N \myLR{et add. marg.} N1}} wamin al-ratbi \edtext{'a`lAhu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'`lAhA} \myLR{GJN}; \tanv{a"'.glAhA} \myLR{K}}} \edtext{\tanv{wamin al-karAmaTi \edtext{'ahannAhA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'asnAhA}\myLR{IO}}} wamin al-manAzili}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wamin al-rU.hi} \myLR{N}}} 'arfa`ahA wamin al-na`mi 'asb.gahA wamin al-qismi \edtext{'a^gzalahu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'a^gzalahA}\myLR{IKN}}} wamin \edtext{al-sayyaraTi}{\Afootnote{\myLR{post corr. K}}} \edtext{a"'`dalahA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'a`lAhA} \myLR{AN}}} wamin al-syAsaTi \edtext{'a.hkamahA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{a"'kmalahA} \myLR{add. marg. I}}}}}{
    %\lemma{\tanv{waal-manAqiba \dots\ 'a.hkamahA}}
    \Afootnote{\myLR{om. D}}} \edtext{wakamala}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wa"'kmala}\myLR{H}}} lahu ha_dihi \edtext{al-fa.dA'ila}{\Afootnote{\myLR{post}\tanv{al-manAqiba} \myLR{trasntulit I}}} \edtext{\edtext{waal-manAqiba}{\Afootnote{\tanv{fI al-manAqiba} \myLR{BK}}} wazayyanahA}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. D}}} bimA qarana \edtext{bihA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{ma`ahA} \myLR{I}; \tanv{i"'layhA}\myLR{add. supra lineam I}; \tanv{bihi} \myLR{J}}} \edtext{min}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. et add. supra lineam J}}} ma.habbaTi \edtext{\tanv{al-`ilmi waal-.hikmaTi}}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-.hikmaTi waal-`ilmi} \myLR{G}}} wa'ahlihA waal-ra.gibaTi fIhA \edtext{\tanv{waal-.hir.si `alY \edtext{i"'stifAdatihA}{\Afootnote{\tanv{'istiflA.hihA} \myLR{A}, \tanv{mA i"'stafAda bihi} \myLR{F}}} \edtext{waal-ba.h_ti}{\Afootnote{\myLR{om. et add. marg. J}}} waal-taqmI^si `mmA \edtext{wa.da`atahu}{\Afootnote{\tanv{wa.da`hu} \myLR{A}}} \edtext{al-`ulamA'_u}{\Afootnote{\tanv{al-.hukamA|"'u} \myLR{G}; \tanv{waal-.hukamA|"'u} \myLR{ante add. I}}} fI kulli naU`iN minhA}}{
    \lemma{\tanv{waal-.hir.si \dots minhA}}
    \Afootnote{\myLR{om. D}}}}}{\lemma{\tanv{a"'mmA \dots minhA}}\Afootnote{\myLR{om. L}}}


\pend
\endnumbering
\end{arab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

I suggest you edit (i.e. reduce) your code to make it a truly *minimal* (the "M" in "[MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)") example. This makes it easier for us to help you.

I tried the following code and I get a similar error to the one you report (at least on some runs. There seem to be instabilities). 

Do you get the error too?

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[series={A}, noend, nopenalties, nofamiliar, noeledsec, noledgroup]{reledmac}

\Xbeforeinserting{\LTR}

\usepackage{arabxetex}

\newcommand{\ta}[1]{\textarab[voc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\tanv}[1]{\textarab[novoc]{#1}}
\newcommand{\myLR}[1]{\textLR{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{arab}
\beginnumbering

\pstart
    \edtext{al-^guz'_u bAbAN}{
    \lemma{al-^guz'_u \dots\ bAbAN}
    \Afootnote{\tanv{al-^guz|"'u  bAbAN} \myLR{B} }}
\pend

\endnumbering
\end{arab}

\end{document}

Comment: Why are only certain footnotes affected?


Well, the errors mention `\@lemma` and 
`\iflemmacommand@`, which according to the reledmac documentation (§ VI.2) handle cases in which “the lemma in the note is different from the lemma in the main text”. I.e. whenever your footnote has different arguments for `\lemma{}` and for `\edtext{}`.
This is the case in my MWE and in some of your footnotes.


I'm afraid I don't have a solution, but I hope someone can pick it up from here!

Comment: Dear @marquinho thank you for your interest. I understand that the example is not "Minimal"... but, as you noticed ("instabilities"), the results are weird, and it seems that the contents or the length matters, this is why I posted a long example.

Comment: As regards \lemma, its use is exactly this: i.e. whenever you do not want \edtext to repeat the whole lemma into the note, then you use \lemma to specify what you want to be written into the note. Therefore, the content of \edtext and \lemma are different (you can see the example in the reledmac documentation).

Comment: I'm keeping troubleshooting and now I have two hints on which I should dig more: 1) it seem that there can be a connection to the length (quantity of characters) in the \edtext (remember that \lemma is always dependent on a \edtext command); 2) XeLaTeX is falsely detecting a control character (}?) because of arabxetex and the ovelapping of unicode and ascii ...?!?

Comment: I suggest you to open a github issue.

Comment: (In your github example, please reduce it to the minimal to reproduce the bug. If possible, only one edtext :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2.38.0 of reledmac solves this issue, linked to "kind of bug" in XeTeX RTL system. [bidi, RTL and \write](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333365/bidi-rtl-and-write)